# Cant resize my partition using gparted

Tags: partitioning

I run Ubuntu 17.04 on my laptop , and it has 2 partitions , sda1 which is the EFI system partition and sda2 which is my main partition.
I want to dualboot windows so naturally i would want to shrink sda2 so i could have some space for windows , but when i tried editing the partition i couldn't change the size , it said the minimum size and maximum size are both the size of my partition.
Note that this partition is mounted , do i need to change the size by booting from a live CD ?

Comment: a partition must be unmounted to make changes to it. boot from  LiveCD or similar media

Comment: If Ubuntu is booting in UEFI boot mode, be sure to install Windows in UEFI mode which requires you to boot installer in UEFI mode. Otherwise it will convert drive to BIOS/MBR erasing entire drive. But you of course have good backups, so any mistake is not a major issue.  If Windows 8 or 10 make sure fast start up is off after install and use Ubuntu live installer to reset ubuntu entry to first in UEFI boot order. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#recommendedpartitionconfigurations

Comment: I use GParted live to Ram through Unetbootin on Ubuntu.